# XNA Content, compile or copy

Tags: compiler-construction, xna

I'm just wondering what the advantages/disadvantage are of using the Content Compiler versus not using it.

I prefer to not compile files, copy them to the output directory and then load them in using other functions rather than 'XNA's' `Content.Load<>()` function. So I'm wondering if this my way works just as good or if I should go back to using the 'XNA' way.

When I load stuff I use the other functions, such as `Texture2D.FromStream()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, the content processor also makes your asset into an .xnb file which is a binary form of the file which is smaller (so your game download is quicker by the user and takes up lees room on their hard dive) and by loading an xnb file from the content.Load<>() method, it will load quicker in game.

Comment: So i could potentially set up some mechanism to swap between 2 different loading types? For example, while developing, use Texture2D.FromStream and for the actual shipping game use the ContentManager.Load<> ?

Comment: What do you mean by "while developing"? I know no benefit to using .FromStream while developing a game. Perhaps if developing a special use tool or something, but I still can't think of a good example.

Comment: Say, when handing your "game" or "engine" to a sound designer, letting him experiment with different assets without having to precompile them and having to install visual studio

Answer (score 2):

The content compiler makes your content crossplatform compatible, that is, it'll be usable on both XBox360 and PC and even Mac with MonoGame.

If you're targeting only PC, you can stick with the .FromStream option, though there's no gain from doing so except for your artists being able to swap resources without recompiling.

Comment: Good answer. How do you make up for missing FromStream methods for various types of content? (or do most types of content offer this method?)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to William's answer (here's [useful link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/11/24/content-pipeline-assemblies.aspx)), [`ContentManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203875.aspx) will also handle disposing of all resources loaded by it automatically. However if you are using only one `ContentManager` that will not make difference (since your resources will be deallocated on game termination).